# merge items into a list based on index

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a dataframe as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(range(4), index=range(4))
df = df.append(df)
```

the resultant df is:

```
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
```

I want to combine the values of the same index into a list. The desired result is:

```
0 [0,0]
1 [1,1]
2 [2,2]
3 [3,3]
```

For a more realistic scenario, my index will be dates, and I want to aggregate multiple obs into a list based on the date. In this way, I can perform some functions on the obs for each date.

Comment: not sure what you're asking to begin with... also, what have you tried yourself?

Comment: Your code will not append you have to do `df=df.append(df)` secondly are you sure you want to do this? do you want to do `df = pd.concat([df,df], axis=1)` to add the dataframe as extra columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For a more realistic scenario, my index will be dates, and I want to
>   aggregate multiple obs into a list based on the date. In this way, I
>   can perform some functions on the obs for each date.

If that's your goal, then I don't think you want to actually materialize a list.  What you want to do is use `groupby` and then act on the groups.  For example:

```
>>> df.groupby(level=0)
<pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0xa861f6c>
>>> df.groupby(level=0)[0]
<pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy object at 0xa86630c>
>>> df.groupby(level=0)[0].sum()
0    0
1    2
2    4
3    6
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

You could extract a list too:

```
>>> df.groupby(level=0)[0].apply(list)
0    [0, 0]
1    [1, 1]
2    [2, 2]
3    [3, 3]
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

but it's usually better to act on the groups themselves.  Series and DataFrames aren't really meant for storing lists of objects.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [374]:

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(4)})
df = df.append(df)
df

Out[374]:
   a
0  0
1  1
2  2
3  3
0  0
1  1
2  2
3  3

[8 rows x 1 columns]

In [379]:
import numpy as np
# loop over the index values and flatten them using numpy.ravel and cast to a list
for index in df.index.values:
    # use loc to select the values at that index
    print(index, list((np.ravel(df.loc[index].values))))
    # handle condition where we have reached the max value of the index, otherwise we output the values twice
    if index == max(df.index.values):
        break
0 [0, 0]
1 [1, 1]
2 [2, 2]
3 [3, 3]
```